# 'How to send Post request using Volley with "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST Request using Volley with the following:

headers:

```
{
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

(Form Data)

```
grant_type=password&client_id=acme&client_secret=acmesecret&username=ayan@vvv.in&password=%2523
```

But I am always getting this error: `E/Volley: [26219] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400`

Here is my code

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.base_url), new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            String resp = response.toString();
            Log.e(TAG,"Response***"+resp);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
            params.put("client_id", "acme");
            params.put("client_secret", "acmesecret");
            params.put("username", "ayan@vvv.in");
            params.put("password", "%2523");
            return params;
        }

    };
    queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are your url containing extra space? Check it carefully.

Comment: I check there is no any extra space

Comment: check with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"